# How long should Coccidia be present after treatment?

Tags: cats, diet, medicines, infections

I have recently adopted a little kitten, about 8 weeks old now. She was from a stray litter and abandoned so I received her quite young (± 4 weeks old). While she is healthy and active in every other regard, she has been suffering with Coccidiosis for the last month.

About 4 days after I got her, I took her to my local vet who diagnosed her after a faecal smear. He gave her a dose of Baycox as well as some other suspension and I received a tube of Pro-Kolin probiotic and Hill's Prescription i/d wet food.

Two weeks or so later, I noticed her stool was still runny every 3 days or so (when the Coccidia emits its egg casings) and so took her back to the vet. He gave her another dose of Baycox and I received more probiotic and i/d food, and she had her first shot.

It has since been another two weeks and she is still very gassy (and it is very powerful!) and having the occasional off-colour, runny stool. I've gotten more probiotic and i/d food (both wet and dry to attempt to get her on a mixed diet) but I'm still worried. My vet said it usually clears in around 3 weeks but it's been much longer now. Should I be worried or is this natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "around 3 weeks" is a general statement, it will have some variance, but on average 2-3 weeks seems to be normal for adult cats, kittens may require more treatment and time. As an aside, felines often clear the condition without need for medication, but medication can speed it up. In terms of concern, dehydration is a big consideration if it's not clearing up. Cats are not big drinkers and so water loss without replenishing is something to keep an eye on and ensure that she's drinking enough (check that her skin elasticity is good and that she's not lethargic).

I think I would give a bit more time. Stress is a real factor and she was abandoned, then taken in, poked, prodded, etc. That's a lot for anyone to take, much less a very young kitten that was likely weaned early and not correctly, extremely stressful for her. However, it sounds, based on your description, that the symptoms are reducing and that's a good sign. Keep in touch with your vet though and let them know what you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to get a bit more information and reassurance (the vet is often very busy and rushed)! She has been drinking a lot (I was worried about dehydration) so that's good and she definitely isn't lethargic (quite the opposite!).